# How to find a sub-sample image from the main image to find gabor filter orientations so as to reduce processing time?

Tags: matlab, computer-vision, filtering, wavelet

I'm trying to find the dominant orientations on an image that is 640 * 480. In general the gabor filter kernel is convolved with all the pixels resulting in a numerically intensive operation. So I wanted to sub-sample the image and find it like in this picture. I'm using matlab for the processing.

[image]

Some ideas I had in mind was,

1. Use `imresize(img,[160,160]);` and resize the image to 160*160.
2. Use `downsample`function of matlab.
   Which do you think, will be best for my purpose?

This is the paper I'm working out. http://pdf.aminer.org/000/128/869/grouping_dominant_orientations_for_ill_structured_road_following.pdf

Comment: Is this a question on asking which resizing paradigm is better, or do you want to determine the orientations in an image using Gabor filters?   Your question says one thing, but your post says another.  Please edit / clarify what you want solved.

Comment: I've edited the question. I want to know the methods with which I can subsample this image. I'm doubtful of the methods I've mentioned.

Comment: `imresize` is perfectly acceptable.  It's the preferred way of resizing an image if you have the image processing toolbox, and it's designed to resize images.  `imresize` is a special case of using `interp2`, but `interp2` is for more general 2D signals.  The beauty with `imresize` is that you can specify the output dimensions of the image.  With `interp2`, you have to specify a 2D grid of co-ordinates that corresponds to the same size as the output image. Determining these exact co-ordinates can be annoying. `imresize` does this under the hood with the output image dimensions you provide.

Comment: Will it be equivalent to selecting a few pixels(say 350) from a large ROI having say 25600 pixels? What I need is to convolve it sparsely, like if this is the array, [1 5 7 9 3 6 8], then I'llbe convolving with only [1 9 8].

Comment: Yes that's possible.  You could resize the ROI, then choose every single point in the ROI after.  This is equivalent to doing a sparse selection of points evenly across the ROI.